# How to refactor tests in tdd?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I'm performing this TDD kata excercise: http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-1

I produced following code (points from 1 to 5 in this excercise - I have unit tests for it):

```
public class StringCalculator
{
    private readonly string[] _defaultSeparators = { ",", "\n" };

    public int Add(string numbers)
    {
        // Parser section (string to list of ints)
        var separators = _defaultSeparators;

        var isSeparatorDefinitionSpecified = numbers.StartsWith("//");
        if (isSeparatorDefinitionSpecified)
        {
            var endOfSeparatorDefinition = numbers.IndexOf('\n');

            var separator = numbers.Substring(2, endOfSeparatorDefinition - 2);

            numbers = numbers.Substring(endOfSeparatorDefinition);
            separators = new[] { separator };
        }

        var numbersArray = numbers.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var numbersArrayAsInts = numbersArray.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

        // Validator section
        var negativeNumbers = numbersArrayAsInts.Where(c => c < 0).ToArray();
        if (negativeNumbers.Any())
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("negatives not allowed ({0})", string.Join(", ", negativeNumbers)));
        }

        return numbersArrayAsInts.Sum();
    }
}
```

Now I want to refactor code to something like this:

```
public int Add(string numbers)
{
    var numbersAsInts = CalculatorNumbersParser.Parse(numbers);

    CalculatorNumbersValidator.Validate(numbersAsInts);

    return numbersAsInts.Sum();
}
```

How I should plan refactor to properly refactor my code and unit tests?

I think that I should move part of tests to new created implementations classes tests (CalculatorNumbersParserTests and CalculatorNumbersValidatorTests), change some existing tests and add tests for Parse and Validate method execution.

But what is the correct way to do this without breaking the tests?

Comment: Just move the code into internal classes that are indirectly tested via the StringCalculator (public) type's tests. Alternatively, the two could also be implemented as private methods in the same type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would caution against moving the tests as if you do this then your tests are tied to the implementation, which means they are very brittle and so you will have to change your tests every time you want to change your implementation. This can quickly become expensive when you have a large code base and can become a prohibiting factor in making changes.

Your existing tests should specify the **behaviour** of your string calculator and so you can refactor your implementation to anything as long as you keep the desired behaviour.

I tend to think of a unit as a 'unit of behaviour' and it may take a few classes to implement this.

Things might change if you were  to place some classes in a different assembly, at which point you would probably want to make some new tests along side the new assembly, to ensure the behaviour of those components is not changed unexpectedly, but in this case I doubt you will be doing this.

Things might also change if you start to reuse the classes in several places, at which point you may want separate tests to specify the behaviour of the classes independently of their use in the places.

Comment: You mean that I should instantiate CalculatorNumbersParser and CalculatorNumbersValidator (not mocks) in my tests? Is that ok in TDD when my unit tests were changed to integration tests?

Comment: it depends on what you consider a 'unit'. I consider a 'unit' as a unit of functionality or behaviour, which may involve several classes. If you do what you are suggesting (have tests for each class independently), in my experience, you will have very brittle tests which you need to spend a lot of effort changing every time you change the code.In ['Art of unit testing'](http://artofunittesting.com/definition-of-a-unit-test/) the definition is `A unit of work can span a single method, a whole class or multiple classes working together to achieve one single logical purpose that can be verified.`

Comment: @czesio: or you might move this functionality to private methods or private class. You need to consider whether their (such classes) existence *outside* of calculator class makes sense; i.e. they represent stand-alone functionality. For this kata excercise such refactorings might be too far-fetched.

Answer (score 3):

I think @Sam Holder has covered most things.  The one thing that I would add is that when you are re-factoring your code you should mark any classes you create that you aren't going to write specific tests for as `internal` (I'm assuming you're using .net), so that they aren't visible outside the assembly they are contained in.

I tend to think `public` classes should be tested in their own right, since they can be instantiated easily by other code the references your assembly.  Whereas, `internal` classes on the other hand can be thought of as implementation details, and can usually be tested through the assemblies public interface.  There are of course exceptions to this, depending on what you're doing / complexity of the code etc. but that's my general rule.

Comment: that's a good general rule, and you can use `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute to make sure that your tests can still see those classes if necessary (which it shouldn't be, but sometimes...)